# How can I return to the form after server side validation with form data intact?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation, asp.net-core-2.1

I have this validation rule to compare two dates:

```
public class EmployeeAbsenceValidator : AbstractValidator<EmployeeAbsence>
{
    public EmployeeAbsenceValidator() {
        RuleFor(a => a.DateTo)
            .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(a => a.DateFrom);
    }
}
```

This is the controller code for validating a newly created absence period:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    EmployeeAbsenceValidator validator = new EmployeeAbsenceValidator();
    ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(employeeAbsence);
    if (!result.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Create", "EmployeeAbsences");
    }
    else
    {
        _context.Add(employeeAbsence);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Employees");
    }
}
```

If the dates are not valid, I want to return to the form with all the form data intact. How do I do that?

Comment: return RedirectToAction("Create", "EmployeeAbsences", employeeAbsence); ?

Comment: @AntoineV Hm... Yes, that seems to do the trick! I guess it's ok to have all the form data in the URL-field. But I wonder if there is some way to avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the Action name is the same for your `GET` and `POST` action methods, then use `return this.View( model )`, like so:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    EmployeeAbsenceValidator validator = new EmployeeAbsenceValidator();
    ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(employeeAbsence);
    if (!result.IsValid)
    {
        return this.View( employeeAbsence );
    }
    else
    {
        _context.Add(employeeAbsence);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Employees");
    }
}
```

This will return the page's HTML to the `POST` request with those validation error messages inside any `@Html.ValidationMessageFor( m => m.Foo` helpers (or `<span asp-validator-for="Foo">` helpers).